# SlimDX Throws An undetermined error occurred when trying Texture2D.ToStream()

Tags: c#, wpf, directx-11, slimdx

Using SlimDX and trying to get a memory stream from a texture. I get the error: E_FAIL: An undetermined error occurred (-2147467259). This should be simple, right?

Here is my device declaration:

```
`d3dDevice11 = new SlimDX.Direct3D11.Device(DriverType.Hardware, DeviceCreationFlags.Debug);
```

And my Texture declaration:

```
Texture2DDescription textureDesc = new Texture2DDescription();
textureDesc.BindFlags = BindFlags.ShaderResource |
                        BindFlags.RenderTarget;
textureDesc.Format = SlimDX.DXGI.Format.B8G8R8A8_UNorm;
textureDesc.Width = _inputWidth;
textureDesc.Height = _inputHeight;
textureDesc.MipLevels = 1;
textureDesc.ArraySize = 1;
textureDesc.SampleDescription = new SlimDX.DXGI.SampleDescription(1, 0);
textureDesc.Usage = ResourceUsage.Default;
textureDesc.OptionFlags = ResourceOptionFlags.Shared;
textureDesc.CpuAccessFlags = CpuAccessFlags.None;
textureDesc.ArraySize = 1;
_texture = new Texture2D(d3dDevice11, textureDesc);
```

And the call to get the Stream:

```
MemoryStream newMemStream = new MemoryStream();
SlimDX.Result sdxRes = SlimDX.Direct3D11.Texture2D.ToFile(
                   _texture.Device.ImmediateContext, 
                   _texture, 
                   SlimDX.Direct3D11.ImageFileFormat.Bmp, 
                   (Stream)newMemStream);
```

Can anyone tell what I am doing wrong?

Thanks,
Doug

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the Texture2D was not available to the CPU. Creating a Texture2D visible from the CPU did the trick.